# Motherboard only has two AUX jacks - but website says it support 5.1

Tags: audio, motherboard, speakers, surround-sound, 5.1

*It was kinda hard to google since most keywords are too common haha
Sorry in advanced if it's common knoledge; Didn't had to work with other motherboards for about 7 years now*

I'm about to buy a new computer and considering the `Gigabyte Z790 Gaming X` as a motherboard, but I am also using Logitech's 5.1 speakers set, which works fine with my current setup ( `Gigabyte H170 Gaming 3` ).

The difference is that I need 3 outputs from the computer - which, right now, I have plenty - but somehow, the new MOBO only has two jacks and the website says it supports 5.1.

I read somewhere that I should connect the rear channel to my front output jack -- but that feels janky AF ( and also, require cable extender, and will make my table even messy-er than it is right now ).

Did someone encountered that with a modern MOBOs? Did you figure it out?

- I'm pretty sure the model of the speakers is z506, but it really doesn't matter - the connectors looks the same ( 3.5mm colored green, black and orange )
- I do not want to buy a PCI card for that.

[Z790 Website](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/Z790-GAMING-X-rev-10#kf)
[H170 Website](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-H170-Gaming-3-rev-10#ov)

Pictures for comparison:

[image: 3-AUX cables (for a total of 6ch) needed]

[image: H170]

[image: Z790]

Comment: [S/PDIF can carry two channels of uncompressed PCM audio or **compressed 5.1 surround sound**.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S/PDIF)

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Yeah but then I'll need some kind of active conversion. I think I'll just buy an external sound card or upgrade the motherboard even more.

Comment: That was gonna be my next suggestion, avoid the janky Mobo

Comment: Also consider that achieving 5.1 surround via independent jacks is probably old tech at this point. Maybe it's time to move on...

Comment: External soundcard, even a cheap brand one (I've got a $15 Soundblaster Play, only 2 channel though), will also avoid electronic noise and AC buzz from the PC.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I'd hardly call 300$ worth of motherboard "janky". Also, the next option ( with ACTUAL 5.1 ) will cost about 450$. Also, buying new speakers will cost me a lot more ( since I love to spend some more, if it means I'll get a better product that'll work for longer )

Comment: @TomášKafka haha you'd think that! I couldn't find anything 5.1 for less than 100-150 bucks... not even including shipping to Asia haha

Comment: @Netan ASRock B660 STEEL LEGEND LGA 1700

Comment: @Netan My bad, the mobo isn't janky but their 5.1 audio solution is.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Yeah, absolutely. It'd seem to be a problem with all Intel boards. During the last hour or so ( since figuring out Intel sucks-er than I thought ), I considered buying 7900X since it's the same price, but the MOBOs are 30% cheaper... then I went into an even worse rabbit hole, when I found out the the NH D15 I ordered won't cool neither 7900X nor 13700K properly. aaaaahhhhh I hate water coolers

Comment: @Netan Hmm, they seem to be extinct, soundblaster had xifi for about $50, but it's sold out. Aliexpress has some cheap ones: CZK 322.60  24％ Off | KEBIDU USB 2.0 Sound Card Audio Card CM6206 Chipset 6 Channel 5.1 Sound Card SPDIF Controller Audio Card for PC Laptop Computer
https://a.aliexpress.com/_m0Lq9SG

Comment: @TomášKafka I have changed the entire specs to fit 7900X haha, alongside a better-fitted RAM, 360AIO CPU Cooler, and of course - 5.1 **NATIVE** motherboard.... I did not know this should be mentioned, but apparently that's the case. I did not even spent much more, since AMD's boards are so cheaper here, for some reason haha

Answer (score 5):

> I read somewhere that I should connect the rear channel to my front output jack -- but that feels janky AF (and also, require cable extender, and will make my table even messy-er than it is right now).

According to [the manual](https://download.gigabyte.com/FileList/Manual/mb_manual_z790-gx-series_e_1101_230406.pdf?v=304a1c45f901d687c303b70de3ad7347#page=15), you are indeed supposed to retask the "front panel" audio jacks (a pin-header on the motherboard) for 5.1 and 7.1 setups.

Audio jacks natively support retasking in most HD-Audio chipsets (i.e. it is not something that only Gigabyte has decided to do), so the "Mic" input can be reconfigured as "Rear Stereo" output. Using the front-panel ones is a bit weird though.

To avoid the cabling mess, you could have the FP_AUDIO connector go to a [backplate like this](https://www.delock.com/produkt/61823/merkmale.html) instead of the actual front-panel ports.

[image: Screenshot of the relevant manual page]

Comment: I actually didn't think of a backplate... So simple and elegant... I just wish I'll remember that in a year from now, when I'll connect something to the front panel and it won't work hahaha. Thanks!!

Comment: Still, janky AF IMHO. Not relatred at all: Linus from LTT recently complained about the prices of MOBOs with diagnostics LED... But damn, I'm gonna pay THAT much for a motherboard without enough 3.5mm jacks... I honestly thinking of buying DDR4 now, so I'll have a real support for 5.1 and pay much less. The struggle is real.

Comment: @Netan stickers over the front ports, or, if they're more your style, those phone charms that plug into headphone sockets

Comment: @Netan Wasn't it Steve Burke from Gamer's Nexus who complained about motherboards?

Comment: @ChrisH haha the problem is that I will need to use that port for output

Comment: @Nzall yup, my bad... Here's the video: https://youtu.be/bEjH775UeNg

Comment: Does that not suggest two AUX jack are enough to transmit 5.1?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin: I don't see how the _three_ checkmarks in the "5.1-channel" column would suggest that?

Comment: It doesn't matter how whichever channels could cope; only whether.

Where does your own Jack Configurations chart hint at how anything might work?

I cannot contribute more…

Answer (score 3):

"Supports 5.1" - it probably does… just not over dedicated analogue outs without some re-jigging involving the front panel jacks too.

The HDMI, S/PDIF & USB, though, will support 5.1, with appropriate 'sound card' adaptor.
*After comments:-*
The 'computer' itself usually can't handle more than stereo because of licensing issues, so it is always handled in separate hardware - whether this is such as a built-in Realtek chip, or an external 'sound card' is actually irrelevant. All consumer audio is transmitted as 'stereo + metadata' from simple 5.1 right up to Dolby Atmos, the decode is done in the final hardware. This applies to USB, HDMI & S/PDIF.

Your simplest option is probably one of these adaptors - S/PDIF is probably going to cause the least amount of interference to your regular workflow - you won't need to specifically route anything to HDMI or USB, it should "just work".
They start for a couple of bucks/quid/euros on eBay - but avoid the very cheapest. By the time you reach $£€ 15-20 you will probably have something reasonably reliable.
The chipsets for these converters were perfected at least a decade ago, so they're cheap & common. I usually tell people to go for the first one they find that comes in a metal case. It seems as good a dividing line as any. They tend to use USB as a power source, with a cheap power-only cable supplied.

Here's one chosen almost at random by searching "USB SPDIF 7.1" on eBay - £15 UK. [Note they all tend to be 7.1 spec rather than 5.1. It makes no practical difference.]

[image]

<sup>Click for full size</sup>

Comment: Also, it DOES support 5.1 analogue audio without converter, apparently.

Comment: Did a comment of mine was erased? I initially said Thanks but I am not interested in external devices... Or, at least, I thought I said it haha

Comment: Well, it's an either/or - an extension cable round from the front of the computer, or this hanging off the back, out of sight, out of mind.

Comment: All USB 2 and higher connections support USB 5.1 audio adapters if the OS supports it. Its not anything to do with the motherboard audio chipset, its handled in software by the OS. So any reference to USB is irrelevant to the motherboards claim to support 5.1 audio.

Comment: @user1937198 - Actually, the USB device must support the 5.1 stream/codec, not the USB port, so this claim is inaccurate. The computer itself will only support stereo without appropriate hardware. This can be included in such as a built-in Realtek chip, or in an external device. Licensing issues prevent 'the computer' itself doing it. Configuration can be in software, but the actual decode is in hardware. All consumer audio streams are technically actually 'stereo + metadata', from 5.1 up to Atmos. This also applies to HDMI & S/PDIF. I've re-worded to clarify this.

Comment: My phrasing was slightly inaccurate, but the point still stands: When it comes to USB, the relevant codec is the the USB adapter chip, and the USB hierarchy _must_ support that device class to be compliant, since it is just opaque frames to it. As such whilst the decode is in hardware, its not on the _motherboard_, and thus irrelevant to the claim that the motherboard supports 5.1 audio. What matters is whether the OS has the software support to feed the audio codec chip in the USB adapter, and whether the external USB adapter has a codec chip capable of 5.1.

Comment: For a motherboard to claim 5.1 whilst only providing USB as a way of providing that capability would be extreamly sketchy. A motherboard USB root hub that was not capable of supporting 5.1 audio adapters would also be extremely suspicious.

Comment: No claim was made as to 5.1 only being supplied from an external device. My initial statement is still true - you ned to use the front jacks… messy. Everything else is just standard fayre for USB, HDMI or S/PDIF. Devices connecting to any of these are class-compliant, and have been for well over a decade.

Comment: @Tetsujin ummmmm so, SPDIF could be an option, but a jenky converter will add lag and might cause more problem than I care to handle.. especially when buying 300$-worth of motherboard ( in my currency, at least ).

Comment: There's zero 'lag' [latency] in S/PDIF. Technically, there's some slight clock jitter, but you will never know that unless you want to analyse data streams;) At consumer level, it's instantaneous.

Comment: and to both of you: If any, I am only gonna use SPDIF out toward a converter like that, so the USB really doesn't matter; The reason is, as I said in another comment somewere on this page - I'm not intersted in connecting chinese devices into my computer... You absolutely may call me a paranoid haha

Comment: @Tetsujin the lag is with the conversion from my digital computer output into analogue output for my speakers. Especially with cheap devices.

Comment: You'll really, really struggle to buy something not originating in China [or predominantly S.E. Asia]. I'd give up that hunt right now. Even Gigabyte is Taiwanese. Logitech's manufacturing is all in SE Asia.

Comment: There is no [human discernible] latency in a DAC itself. The real latency in computer audio is in the computer itself; but that's automatically compensated for in such as video sync.

Comment: I'd love to comment on that: I work in cybersecurity. I have a secured network and over-all pretty secured environment. I'm not doing anything sensitive, but I prefer to avoid problems. I'm also not installing application on my phone when I don't know them. Every day apps from the IOS/Google stores are being taken down after discovered to deploy malware. Why avoiding unknown devices is so weird to you? Of course I'll avoid using devices that are not commonly-used and tested. Anyhow, If you want to discuss this further, we can continue in the chat, I think? I'm pretty new around here

Comment: Well, if you think there's some way an S/PDIF DAC interface can phone home to China, I'm all ears once you show me how.

Comment: When is connected to USB? It can do A LOT of things... Just visit hak5 store to get an idea. Now imagine the same stuff, just 90% cheaper, from AliExpress or some other website. Could easily make you a part of a botnet, and you won't even realize why your internet's been so slow lately.

Comment: I said S/PDIF, it's everybody else that's banging on about USB. Anyway, thy're all made in China these days. No getting away from that.